# How to retrieve the session values in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I am facing the problem with Yii 2 session when I add the products to the cart session and fetch session cart values.

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
exit;
```

I got this line.

```
Array ( [__flash] => Array ( ) [__id] => 65 )
```

Also while trying Yii 2 way:

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
print_r($session);
exit;
```

I am getting this value:

```
yii\web\Session Object ( 
    [flashParam] => __flash 
    [handler] => [_cookieParams:yii\web\Session:private] => Array ( [httponly] => 1 ) 
    [_hasSessionId:yii\web\Session:private] => 1   
    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) 
    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] =>
```

How to get the session data with keys and values in Yii 2?

Answer (score 4):

Hi Sai you can set or retrieve the session value in yii2 easily by using the following steps

1) To set session value on var 'userVariable'

```
Yii::$app->session->set('userVariable','1234');
```

2) For getting the session value of var 'userVariable'

```
$userVariable = Yii::$app->session->get('userVariable');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get session by using `$session = Yii::$app->session;` hope it will help you :)

Comment: Iam using also what you said, but it didn'

Comment: Iam using also what you said, but it didn't get the values, i updated my explanation, plz see. @Amit Sahu

Comment: In Yii2 you can access the identity interface for the current user by using the identityInterface object from within the \yii\web\User class with something like this 
\Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to open session

```
Yii::$app->session->open();
```

And you can get all session using `$_SESSION`

```
var_dump($_SESSION);exit;
```

May be useful!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to start session IF you are using YII2 framework.
Follow these step:
1. $session = Yii::$app->session;
2. $session->set('key', 'value');
3. $session->get('key');

Otherwise directly set value

$session['key']=>'value'

Comment: can you explain briefly?

Comment: Can you explain briefly with example? @Saleem Khan

Comment: Sai, You need to add direct value in session like this

Comment: Sai, You need to add direct value in session like this
1. Start session 
$session = Yii::$app->session; 
2. add value in session
$session->set('1', 'sam'); 
3. this way you will get value from session
$session->get('1');

Answer (score 0):

you can get session ID with

```
Yii::$app->user->id
//OR
Yii::$app->user->identity->id
```

and you can set new session with

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session->set('new-name-session', '1234');
```

check all session with

```
var_dump($_SESSION);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to process `Yii::$app->session` object in `for/foreach` loop, like so:

```
foreach (Yii::$app->session as $key => $value) { 
        var_dump($value); 
}
```