# Yii2.0 / Session INSIDE a formular

Tags: yii2

What ist yii2.0 analogy to following php-command?

```
<input type="text" name="zahl_down" id="zahl" value="<?php if (!empty($_SESSION['zahl_down'])) echo $_SESSION['zahl_down'];?>"></p>
```

All I achieved is code like this,which is not as it should be,of course:

```
   <?= $form->field($model, 'zahl_up')->hint("Ihr zuvor eingegebener Wert:".$session['zahl_up']) ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is giving you problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that this happens in a form does not affect how sessions work.

See [How to retrieve the session values in Yii 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361322/how-to-retrieve-the-session-values-in-yii-2) for a quick how-to on Yii 2 session handling.

Comment: I know how to handle sessions. I search a possibility to use them inside a formular!